# Подключение и использование своего java-приложения в Play Framework'е

Tags: java, playframework

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как подключить написанное мною java-приложение и использовать его функции в `Play Framework'e`. Т.е. у меня есть приложение поиска файлов на диске. Мне нужно вызвать это приложение и отобразить в `html` странице результат поиска (в `Play framework'e 1.2.***`)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - оформить ваше приложение в виде jar библиотеки и положить к библиотекам web приложения play'a. Далее в play'е вы пишете свой контроллер, который использует ваши классы для получения информации.